# Taiwanese traveling to Xiamen, China - do I need to get a visa or Tai Bao Zheng before I go?

Tags: china, us-citizens, taiwan, permits, taiwanese-citizens

**Me**: US passport and Taiwan passport

**Trip**: Going to Taiwan for a few weeks but also planning on going to Xiamen from Taiwan for a few days.

**Problem**: So far, it seems like it is more annoying to use my US passport to get a visa for China.  I'm wondering if I should wait until I get to Taiwan to obtain the necessary permits with my Taiwanese passport. Where / How would I go about doing that?  Also, I heard a friend say that I can just fly into China and get the necessary permits after I land.  Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just asked my Taiwanese friend. She said you have to apply for Tai BaoZheng which can easily be obtained in Taiwan through China Travel Agency. It normally takes 1-2 days. And you can also fly to China and get the Tai BaoZheng at the airport. However, not all airports have the equipments to do that you have to check with the embassy which airport can do that.